# AngularJS cant get category "All" while filtering

Tags: angularjs

I started to play with angular and I am trying to write a simple app that consists of categories containing items. ( I am trying to implement a tutorial for my needs )

Now I am trying to add a filter to select items by categories. I can filter them unless I choose All categories. I cant get all the categories.
I have edges service :

```
angular.module('swFrontApp')
  .controller('EdgesController', function ($scope, edges,categories) {
    $scope.edges = edges.query();
    $scope.categories = categories.query();

    $scope.filterBy = {
        search: '',
        category: $scope.categories[0]
    };


    var selectedEdge = null;

    $scope.selectEdge = function(edge) {
        selectedEdge = (selectedEdge === edge) ? null : edge;
    };

    $scope.isSelected = function(edge)  {
        return edge === selectedEdge;
    };
    $scope.displayRequirements = function(reqs) {
        var result = '';

        for ( var i = 0; i < reqs.length; i ++) {
            if (result !== '' ) { result += ', '}
            if (reqs[i].name) {
                result += reqs[i].name+ ' ';
            }
            result +=  reqs[i].value;
        }
        return result;
    };
  });
```

and I try to filter them using  :

```
angular.module('swFrontApp').filter('edges', function() {
    return function(edges, filterBy) {
        return edges.filter( function( element, index, array ) {
            return element.category.name === filterBy.category.name; 
        });
    };
} );
```

Here is my html to get edges with categories filter

```
<select 
            name="category" 
            ng-model="filterBy.category"
            ng-options="c.name for c in categories"
            class="form-control"></select>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat-start="edge in edges | filter:{name: filterBy.search}| edges: filterBy " ng-click="selectEdge(edge)">
            <span class="label label-default">{{ edge.category.name }}</span>
            {{edge.name}}
            <span class="text-muted">({{ displayRequirements(edge.requirements) }})</span>
        </li>
        <li ng-repeat-end ng-show="isSelected(edge)">
            {{edge.description}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I formed My [Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/E5o2Pp4NADDuFlnz8KMh) is here.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because of the `category.name` attribute. In your `categoriesService.js` you return collection where `name` equals to `All`. But if you look into `EdgesService` file, you'll see that there is no such option as 'All'. So this comparison in `script.js` file (in your filter)

```js
return element.category.name === filterBy.category.name;
```

will always return false when `filterby.category.name` equals to 'All'.

The way to fix it is to change it to something like this:

```js
return element.category.name === filterBy.category.name || filterBy.category.name === 'All';
```

This way it will always return `true` if 'All' category is selected.

Also later in the course rank option will be introduced as well. You can browse the code for that project here: https://github.com/Remchi/sw-front

Hope that helps. :)